# Having some problem adding list values ​in loop

Tags: python

My code:

```
a = {}
b = []

for i in range(1, 5):    
  a["Name"] = i
  print(a)
  b.append(a)

print(b)
```

result is `[{'Name': 4}, {'Name': 4}, {'Name': 4}, {'Name': 4}]`

how to make `[{'Name': 1}, {'Name': 2}, {'Name': 3}, {'Name': 4}]`

Comment: you're always modifying the same object, instead of creating a new one to append each time.

Comment: You made one dictionary. It sounds like you intend to make four. If you want to make a dictionary inside the loop, then you should make it inside the loop

Comment: Move `a = {}` so it is inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @njzk2 said, you are modifying the same object.

```py
b = []

for i in range(1, 5):    
  a = {}
  a["Name"] = i
  print(a)
  b.append(a)

print(b)
```

This will fix it.

```
{'Name': 1}
{'Name': 2}
{'Name': 3}
{'Name': 4}
[{'Name': 1}, {'Name': 2}, {'Name': 3}, {'Name': 4}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are appending the same object over and over. The dictionary `a` only gets created once. You *modify* it on each loop iteration, but it's still the same dictionary, so you see the results of the last modification four times.

You want to generate a *new* dictionary on each loop iteration. Note there is no need to create an empty dictionary and then assign to a key. In this case we can simply use a dictionary literal with thatt key/value pair.

```
b = []

for i in range(1,5):    
  a = {'name': i}
  print(a)
  b.append(a)

print(b)
```

Or if you don't need `print(a)` you can do this more concisely with a list comprehension.

```
b = [{'name': i} for i in range(1, 5)]
print(b)
```